# Unity - Resolve generic implementation that inherits from T

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container

I'm using Unity and want to resolve all implementations which have a generic type that is assignable from a specific type.

I currently do the registrations like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IPerson>, PersonQueryGenerator>("1");
container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<ICustomer>, CustomerQueryGenerator>("2");
container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IEmployee>, EmployeeQueryGenerator>("3");
container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IManager>, ManagerQueryGenerator>("4");
```

Then the hierarchy goes like this:

```
public interface IPerson
{
}

public interface ICustomer : IPerson
{
}

public interface IEmployee : IPerson
{
}

public interface IManager : IEmployee
{
}
```

And the interface of the implementations that I'm trying to resolve:

```
public interface IQueryGenerator<T>
{
   IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>  GenerateQueries();
}
```

Now I want to be able to resolve all IQueryGenerators where the generic type is assignable to the type I have. So I have a factory which is supposed to wrap it:

```
    public class QueryFactory
    {
        private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

        public QueryFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>> GenerateQueries<TModel>()
        {
            // Get all querygenerators which can handle TModel.
            IQueryGenerator<TModel>[] queryGenerators = _container.ResolveAll<IQueryGenerator<TModel>>();
            foreach (var queryGenerator in queryGenerators)
            {
                // Do something with queryGenerator.
                var result = queryGenerator.GenerateQueries();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want is that `_container.ResolveAll<IQueryGenerator<IEmployee>>()` returns `PersonQueryGenerator`, `EmployeeQueryGenerator` and `ManagerQueryGenerator` because `IManager` is an `IEmployee` and `IEmployee` is a `IPerson`.

`_container.ResolveAll<IQueryGenerator<ICustomer>>()` returns `PersonQueryGenerator`, and `CustomerQueryGenerator`.

`IEmployee` can be casted down to `IPerson`, which can be handled by `PersonQueryGenerator`.

How do I register the IQueryGenerators, and how do I resolve them based on `TModel`? Or is there any other way to retrieve the QueryGenerators based upon the interfaces `TModel` implement?

EDIT:

I've added a proof-of-concept of what I want to do. It works well, but is very hard-coded.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<IManager> managers = new List<IManager>
        {
            new Manager()
            {
                Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Name = "Executive Manager",
                EmployeeNumber = 9,
                IsExecutive = true,
                Salary = 1000
            },
            new Manager()
            {
                Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                Name = "Ordinary Manager",
                EmployeeNumber = 8,
                IsExecutive = false,
                Salary = 900
            },
        };
        var queries = GenerateQueries();

        managers = queries.Aggregate(managers, (current, expression) => current.Where(expression));
        foreach (var manager in managers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Manager: {0}", manager.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    // Change this to a generic method.
    static IEnumerable<Func<IManager, bool>> GenerateQueries()
    {
        // Change this to a more generic management
        IList<IQueryGenerator<IManager>> queryGenerators = new List<IQueryGenerator<IManager>>();
        if (typeof(IPerson).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IManager)))
        {
            queryGenerators.Add(new PersonQueryGenerator());
        }
        if (typeof(IEmployee).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IManager)))
        {
            queryGenerators.Add(new EmployeeGenerator());
        }
        if (typeof(IManager).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IManager)))
        {
            queryGenerators.Add(new ManagerQueryGenerator());
        }

        // Fetch queries and return them.
        var queries = new List<Func<IManager, bool>>();
        foreach (var queryGenerator in queryGenerators)
        {
            // Do something with queryGenerator.
            queries.AddRange(queryGenerator.GenerateQueries());
        }
        return queries;
    }

    // I want to use this method instead.
    static IEnumerable<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateQueries<TModel>()
    {
        // Do the same thing as the method above
        //TODO: Resolve all IQueryGenerators that can handle TModel.
        return null;
    }
}

public interface IQueryGenerator<in T>
{
    IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> GenerateQueries();
}

public class ManagerQueryGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IManager>
{
    public IEnumerable<Func<IManager, bool>> GenerateQueries()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ManagerQueryGenerator called");
        yield return x => x.IsExecutive;
    }
}

public class PersonQueryGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IPerson>
{
    public IEnumerable<Func<IPerson, bool>> GenerateQueries()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PersonQueryGenerator called");
        yield return x => x.Birthday > DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class EmployeeGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IEmployee>
{
    public IEnumerable<Func<IEmployee, bool>> GenerateQueries()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("EmployeeGenerator called");
        yield return x => x.Salary > 900;
    }
}

public interface IHaveName
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IPerson : IHaveName
{
    DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}

public interface ICustomer : IPerson
{
    int MoneyToSpend { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployee : IPerson
{
    int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    int Salary { get; set; }
}

public interface IManager : IEmployee
{
    bool IsExecutive { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : IManager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public bool IsExecutive { get; set; }
}
```

Output is:

```
PersonQueryGenerator called
EmployeeGenerator called
ManagerQueryGenerator called
Manager: Executive Manager
```

This is what I want, but with a more generic type management and I really would like to use `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` because it will be used with EF.

```
public interface IQueryGenerator<T>
{
   IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>  GenerateQueries();
}
```

Instead of:

```
public interface IQueryGenerator<in T>
{
   IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>>  GenerateQueries();
}
```

Comment: But what would be the type of `queryGenerators`?  an `object[]`?

Comment: But is `IQueryGenerator<IPerson>` assignable from `IQueryGenerator<IManager>`? I don't think so.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - No, you're absolutely right. They are not assignable from eachother. However, IPerson is assignable from IManager and I would like Unity to understand that. But maybe it's not possible?

Comment: I don't think this can work because the types are not compatible. How would you use the return value of `GenerateQueries`? What would be the type of `result`? and how would you consume it?

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I've updated the question with a proof of concept that runs. However, it doesn't use Generic. But it shows that you can use different IQueryGenerators for the same model as long as the model is assignable for some interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with little bit reflection when you're filling the unity container.

```
private static UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

static void RegisterGenerator<T, TG>() where TG : IQueryGenerator<T>
{
  var assembly = typeof(T).Assembly;
  // walk trough all interfaces in assembly, if the interface inherits from
  // typeof(T), add that particular IQueryGenerator<> to container as well
  foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
  {
    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsInterface)
    {
      var generatorType = typeof(IQueryGenerator<>).MakeGenericType(type);
      container.RegisterType(generatorType, typeof(TG), type.Name);
    }
  }
}

static IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> GenerateQueries<T>() where T : IPerson
{
  var queryGenerators = container.ResolveAll<IQueryGenerator<T>>().ToList();

  // Fetch queries and return them.
  var queries = new List<Func<T, bool>>();
  foreach (var queryGenerator in queryGenerators)
  {
    // Do something with queryGenerator.
    queries.AddRange(queryGenerator.GenerateQueries());
  }
  return queries;
}
```

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  RegisterGenerator<IPerson, PersonQueryGenerator>();
  RegisterGenerator<IManager, ManagerQueryGenerator>();

  var managers = new List<IPerson>
  {
    new Manager
    {
      Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
      Name = "Executive Manager",
      EmployeeNumber = 9,
      IsExecutive = true,
      Salary = 1000
    },
    new Manager
    {
      Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
      Name = "Ordinary Manager",
      EmployeeNumber = 8,
      IsExecutive = false,
      Salary = 900
    }
  }.AsEnumerable();
  var queries = GenerateQueries<IPerson>();

  managers = queries.Aggregate(managers, (current, expression) => current.Where(expression));
  foreach (var manager in managers)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Manager: {0}", manager.Name);
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Unity;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            container.RegisterType<Manager>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IPerson, Manager>();
            container.RegisterType<IEmployee, Manager>();
            container.RegisterType<IManager, Manager>();
            container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IPerson>, PersonQueryGenerator>();
            container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IEmployee>, EmployeeGenerator>();
            container.RegisterType<IQueryGenerator<IManager>, ManagerQueryGenerator>();

            IEnumerable<IManager> managers = new List<IManager>
            {
                new Manager()
                {
                    Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                    Name = "Executive Manager",
                    EmployeeNumber = 9,
                    IsExecutive = true,
                    Salary = 1000
                },
                new Manager()
                {
                    Birthday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    Name = "Ordinary Manager",
                    EmployeeNumber = 8,
                    IsExecutive = false,
                    Salary = 900
                },
            };

            // Fetch queries and return them.
            var queries = new List<Func<IManager, bool>>();
            queries.AddRange(GenerateQueries<IPerson>());
            queries.AddRange(GenerateQueries<IEmployee>());
            queries.AddRange(GenerateQueries<IManager>());

            managers = queries.Aggregate(managers, (current, expression) => current.Where(expression));
            foreach (var manager in managers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Manager: {0}", manager.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // I want to use this method instead.
        private static IEnumerable<Func<TModel, bool>> GenerateQueries<TModel>()
        {
            var queryGenerator = container.Resolve<IQueryGenerator<TModel>>();

            return queryGenerator.GenerateQueries();
        }
    }

    public interface IQueryGenerator<in T>
    {
        IEnumerable<Func<T, bool>> GenerateQueries();
    }

    public class ManagerQueryGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IManager>
    {
        public IEnumerable<Func<IManager, bool>> GenerateQueries()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ManagerQueryGenerator called");
            yield return x => x.IsExecutive;
        }
    }

    public class PersonQueryGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IPerson>
    {
        public IEnumerable<Func<IPerson, bool>> GenerateQueries()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PersonQueryGenerator called");
            yield return x => x.Birthday > DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeGenerator : IQueryGenerator<IEmployee>
    {
        public IEnumerable<Func<IEmployee, bool>> GenerateQueries()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EmployeeGenerator called");
            yield return x => x.Salary > 900;
        }
    }

    public interface IHaveName
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPerson : IHaveName
    {
        DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICustomer : IPerson
    {
        int MoneyToSpend { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEmployee : IPerson
    {
        int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        int Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IManager : IEmployee
    {
        bool IsExecutive { get; set; }
    }

    public class Manager : IManager
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public bool IsExecutive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: PersonQueryGenerator called
EmployeeGenerator called
ManagerQueryGenerator called
Manager: Executive Manager